# findAll exceptions with named parameters

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I'm trying to do a findAll similar to one of the grails examples. This is what I have:

```
def beverage = Beverage.findAll("from Beverage as b where b.id in (:ids)",[ids: [1,2]])
```

and I'm getting:

> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to coerce the hard-coded ids to longs:

```
[ids: [1L, 2L]]
```